# How should I link these models to query multi tables via CakePHP associations?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.3.2 and I need to do a query on multi tables.

I have this database:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|    Users     |    Agents     |    Companies    |    Ads    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|      id      |      id       |       id        |    id     |
|    username  |      name     |     company     |   title   |
|    password  |    lastname   |      sector     |  message  |
|              |     user_id   |     user_id     |  user_id  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

These are the associations (Models):

**User**

- hasOne Agent
- hasOne Company
- hasMany Ads

**Agent**

- belongsTo User

**Company**

- belongsTo User

**Ad**

- belongsTo User

(***NOTE:*** *Please, keep in mind that when I add a new user that user could be an Agent **OR** a Company*.)

**QUESTION:**

In my **AdsController** I have an action named **view**, there I read two params that I receve from Route:

```
$this->params['id']
$this->params['sector']
```

I need to do a query to check if the ***id*** is really associated to an **Ad.id** and If the ***sector*** is associated to **Company.sector**

I would like to check it with **ONE find('first')** ***instead of*** checking

1. If the ID exists
2. If the sector exists and it is associated to the user_id

How could I do it ?

*(If the query finds Ad.id and Company.sector I need to retrieve all fields of Ad and Company)*

---

At the moment my **find('first'**) in AdsController/view is:

```
$options = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Ad.*'
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'User' => array(
            'Company' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'Company.*'
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Company.sector' => $this->params['sector'],
                ),
            )       
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Ad.id' => $this->params['id'],
    )
)

$data = $this->Ad->find('first', $options);
debug($data);
```

The problem is that **Company** is now shown in the result (array).

Please, keep in mind that I only need to retrieve the array IF:

- The ID of the AD exists
- The sector of the Company exists

If one of above are not "true" I would like to get an empty array.

*Obviously I have added Containable behavior in Ad model.*

Comment: Don't `select *`. Plus Cake will do this automatically. Company will be included as you've asked it to be included in your Contain. If no record matches the foreign key it will be empty.

Comment: @DavidYell as I wrote the company is not shown. I only see Ad and User array in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this, had same problem that for some reason contain, kinda malfunctions with that array() structure, maybe it works how it means to be, but I dont get it, anyways to retrive chain dependencies i use this kind of construction:

```
$options = array(
        'contain' => array(
            'User',
            'User.Company' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Company.sector' => $this->params['sector'],
                ),
            )                   
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Ad.id' => $this->params['id'],
        )
    )
```

But, you need to have in mind that conditions in contain are not the same as the conditions for main model, therfore even if the company sector does not exist but Ad with given id exits you will not receive an empty set. As far as I know you cannot use a condition to exclude results if there is no direct association between models. So you would still need to check if `$result['User']['Company']` is an empty set or not.

One more thing your query array does not match structure you've provided with your question, there is no field `sector` in your `Company` table

Comment: I have corrected the database structure. My wrong... Ok I will try to use 'User.Company'... but this is strange, reading the doc (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) I see that I do not need to use Model1.Model2

Comment: Using dot notation is the same as array nesting.

Comment: @DavidYell yes I'm aware of that, but for some reason, unchecked so far, the dot notation worked for me unlike array nesting in contain